# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I've created a data set with Mockaroo and then added the file with cmd. But I am getting this error.
**ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric:**
The table definiton is this :

```
create table car(
id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
make VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
price NUMERIC(19,2) NOT NULL);
```

And this is how the numeric number (price) looks like:

```
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (1, 'Mercury', 'Grand Marquis', '$52656.16');
```

I added the cmd screen shot for you to see.

Note : the translated version of the error written in my cmd is:

**ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric:**

p.s : I tried making (19,2) to even (50,20).  It did not work.

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyCbN.png)

Comment: Remove the dollar sign.  It is not part of a number value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `price` column is numeric and data that you are entering into it is varchar(`'$52656.16'`)

Either replace `'$52656.16'` with numeric value `52656.16` or change `price` column to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VARCHAR for the price column you may still get a  invalid input syntax for type numeric error.

What i think you should try is changing the data sets from mockaroo by changing the money option with numbers and add the decimals (you can choose 2 decimals option) option. You should have a data set without the $ sign.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30721884)